# Custom Variable Plain Value in Email template

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, custom-variable

I'm aware that it's possible to call the HTML value by:
`{{customVar code=custom_variable_code}}`

Question is simple:
Is it possible to receive **plain value** of custom variable in email template (Magento 1.9.2.0) with some statement like:
`{{customVar code=custom_variable_code|plain}}`?
If it's not, are there any tips to get something like that to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is but it'll require some coding.

In a nutshell this is how an email is sent

```
$template  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('[email identifier]');                                  

$template->send('email@domain.com','John Doe', array(
   'myvar' => 'foo',
   'myvar2' => 'bar',
));
```

now we can access the variables using `{{var myvar}}` and `{{var myvar2}}`

So to inject your values you'll need to make modifications to the array with variables injected into the `send` method.

It depends on what email you want to change

Comment: I was thinking about using it in almost all email templates - to be more specific in their subjects. But as I see the more quicker and cleaner approach is to just create dedicated for emails custom variable with text value entered in html – then it's accessible everywhere without any reinventing of the wheel. Only hiccup is that there will be two same custom variables but one with i.e. email prefix.

Comment: @versedi hold one sec, let me check if there is an event you can use to inject them into every email\

Comment: ok say there isn't an event but you could rewrite `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter` from a custom module setting your vars in the `_construct` method or rewrite `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template` setting them in the `send` method. It ain't perfect but it'll get the job done